# why is the result showing segmentation fault?

Tags: c

The program ask the user to enter the two values, after storing the values in the pointers, it print segmentation fault and terminate.why?

```
// c program to add two numbers using pointers

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *ptr1, *ptr2, sum;

    printf ("Enter the two numbers:\n");
    scanf ("%d %d", ptr1, ptr2);

    sum = *ptr1 + *ptr2;
    printf("The result is %d", sum);
    return 0;
```

Comment: You've declared pointers but aren't pointing them at anything.  You're writing into random memory you don't own.

Comment: Why you even declare them as pointers?

Comment: @Ari0nhh: Probably because `scanf()` wants two `int *` arguments for the given format string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you can write  "scanf ("%d %d", &intVar1, &intVar2);", where intVar1 and intVar2 are int variables.

Comment: @MayurK: yes, that had crossed my mind as a possibility — see this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231509/why-is-the-result-showing-segmentation-fault#comment67725864_40231566).

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have not allocated memory for ptr1 and ptr2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *ptr1=0, *ptr2=0, sum=0;

    ptr1= malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(0 == ptr1) //Check if mem allocation is successful.
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory for ptr1\n");
        return 0;
    }

    ptr2= malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(0 == ptr2) //Check if mem allocation is successful.
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory for ptr2\n");
        free(ptr1); //Free ptr1 memory
        return 0;
    }

    printf ("Enter the two numbers:\n");
    scanf ("%d %d", ptr1, ptr2);

    sum = *ptr1 + *ptr2;
    printf("The result is %d", sum);

    free(ptr2); //Free ptr2 memory
    free(ptr1); //Free ptr1 memory
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As AriOnhh mentioned in a comment to your question, you don't need pointers for this simple program.

Comment: Well, I suppose it does the job (apart from not checking that the memory allocations worked).  But why not `int val1, val2, sum;` and `scanf("%d %d", &val1, &val2);` and `sum = val1 + val2;`?  I'm not sure of the benefit of initializing the pointers — they're set by their respective calls to `malloc()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Yes we can do that. I was answering why it was giving segmentation fault and how to fix that. I think this program is part of some complex program and rhuann made it simple to ask the question. So I retained his pointer variables.

Comment: i am trying to clear my understanding on pointers

Comment: Yup; and there's also the comment that says `program to add two numbers using pointers`.  Another, other way is `int val1, val2, *ptr1 = &val1, *ptr2 = &val2;`.  There are many ways of (politically incorrect treatment of cats removed) dealing with it.

Comment: @rhuann: the key thing with pointers — all pointers — is to know what they're pointing at.  Is the value in the pointer pointing at some memory that it is still valid to access?  If not, all sorts of troubles can occur.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added checks for memory allocations. I think it should be fine now.

Comment: Error messages can usefully be reported on `stderr` — the standard error channel.  But otherwise, yes.  I'm not sure I'd be using `malloc()` for someone struggling with pointers, but their time will come (tomorrow or the day after, probably).